# GCM FC / sender id not set on constructor

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I have gotten some strange StackTraces from users of my app recently:

```
Android Version: 2.3.5
Phone Model: GT-I9001
Stacktrace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: sender id not set on constructor
at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.getSenderIds(GCMBaseIntentService.java:125)
at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:237)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I am using Rev. 3 of the GCM lib and regarding to the documentation the senderID is not needed to be passed by the constructor anymore ( was that way in C2DM times ) - also this does not crash on my devices and on the devices of a lot of other users. Can somebody shed a light on what is happening on these devices and idealy has some workaround? A non working GCM for these users would be an option for me as device push is optional - but I do not want it to crash ..

Edit here is the source used:
https://github.com/ligi/gobandroid/blob/master/src/org/ligi/gobandroid_hd/GCMIntentService.java

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you override the method `getSenderIds(Context context)` from GCMBaseIntentService? From the source code, it mentioned if you do not pass in a SenderID in the constructor, then you need to override `getSenderIds(Context context)` to provide a SenderID.

Here's the comment from the constructor:

```
/**
 * Constructor that does not set a sender id, useful when the sender id
 * is context-specific.
 * <p>
 * When using this constructor, the subclass <strong>must</strong>
 * override {@link #getSenderIds(Context)}, otherwise methods such as
 * {@link #onHandleIntent(Intent)} will throw an
 * {@link IllegalStateException} on runtime.
 */
protected GCMBaseIntentService() {
    this(getName("DynamicSenderIds"), null);
}
```

And the comment for getSenderIds():

```
/**
 * Gets the sender ids.
 *
 * <p>By default, it returns the sender ids passed in the constructor, but
 * it could be overridden to provide a dynamic sender id.
 *
 * @throws IllegalStateException if sender id was not set on constructor.
 */
protected String[] getSenderIds(Context context) {
    if (mSenderIds == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("sender id not set on constructor");
    }
    return mSenderIds;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have not overwritten this constructor here is the source https://github.com/ligi/gobandroid/blob/master/src/org/ligi/gobandroid_hd/GCMIntentService.java

also the doc here: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html states nothing about overwriting getSenderIds

Comment: If you have the GCM extras installed, then you will have access to the source code of GCMBaseIntentService.java, take a look at that file and that's what mentioned in the source code.

Comment: I am not yet 100% about this whole thing but I accept and upvote your answer as I am thankful for it!

Comment: @vipsy yea this seems to work - havent got any of those error messages anymore

Comment: It is now also mentioned in the GCM docs at the end of step 2 here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app

Answer (score 12):

Quoting from a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-gcm/bXQCHuZmK-g) response:

> It looks like you're using the default constructor without overriding
>   the getSenderIds() method. As the constructor's javadoc explains:
>
> Constructor that does not set a sender id, useful when the sender id
>   is context-specific. When using this constructor, the subclass must
>   override getSenderIds(Context), otherwise methods such as
>   onHandleIntent(Intent) will throw an IllegalStateException on runtime
>
> If you don't need a dynamic sender id, you should use the constructor
>   that takes the sender id instead.

UPDATE: I think I solved.

Look inside the GCM examples, you have to implemnt this if you use the supert constructor with static YOUR_GCM_SENDER_ID (

```
public GCMIntentService() {
        super(YOUR_GCM_SENDER_ID);
}
```

Otherwise, if you use the super constructor without params, you have to override getSenderIds(Context)

Everything it's explained in [JavaDoc documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#GCMBaseIntentService%28%29)

**UPDATE: Explaining what is YOUR_GCM_SENDER_ID**

When you configurd your Google API Project on [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) page you have to create your own project and enable GCM API on it.

You project url will be something like

```
https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:4815162342
```

The value after #project: (4815162342 in this example) is your project number, and it will be used later on as the GCM sender ID.

Comment: Here the "Global.GCM_SENDER_ID" is the value like 2372498294 that @StErMi acquired via his GCM setup with Google, and has put into his app as a constant. The value is the same sender id that is used in GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);